# How to update license key in SCOM 2012 after eval period expires?

Tags: scom, licensing

Does anyone know how to update the license key for SCOM 2012 after the evaluation period expires.  My scom server will not allow me to connect and will not allow me to update the key using the power shell cmdlets now that the eval period has expired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that is solved when installing upate rollup 2. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2706783/en-us

Issue 2

The Set-SCOMLicense cmdlet fails if the management group evaluation expiration time-out has expired.

So install update rollup 2 en retry inserting the license key.